# Thermal imaging camera

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, home-experiment

I'm making a tea bag experiment (Make a hollow cylindrical tube from light paper e.g. from an empty tea bag. When the top end of the cylinder is lit, it takes off.) I need to know how hot air is moving so please help me if you have  thermal imaging camera or with out it write your opinion

Comment: http://physicsbuzz.physicscentral.com/2012/03/party-trick-flying-fiery-tea-bags.html

Comment: I know the main idea but I would like to know the character of air movement . Thank you in advance.

Comment: The character of the air movement is turbulent.  It has a Reynolds number, which can give you a rough characterization of the behavior, based on the width of the tube, the density of the air (a function of it's temperature and pressure) and the viscosity (also a function of temperature and pressure).  The concise answer is: It's complicated.  Real complicated.

Comment: Removed the -1 by adding a +1. Can you please stop the ridiculous drive by negative voting???

Comment: how can I calculate pressure?

Comment: Hi there @AntillarMaximus: I believe that the automatic down-vote is caused by the SE engine for non-constructive posts..!